# Fail during georeferencing an old map

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, georeferencing

I want to georeferencine an old map, but unfortunately, it failed.
I use QGIS 3.28 LTR to conduct this task. The process which I have conducted as follows:

1. This is the projection which is written in the map. The map is located in UTM 49S
   [image]

[image]

2. These are the GCPs (Ground Control Points) that I made
   [image]

The GCPs that I put are located in the grid which is provided in the map.

3. I try to set the target CRS in the dialogue of Transformation Setting, but I cannot find the projection "Lambert Conical Orthomorphic" in the list. I also have tried to put the UTM 49S as the target CRS, but the result is not what I expected like in the point 4 below.
4. And this is the result which I don't expect.
   [image]

How can I solve my issue?

Comment: Which CRS exactly have you used? Have you considered using an old CRS?

Comment: [Case Closed]
I can successfully georeference my map by creating custom projection.

Comment: Would you please share your custom projection as an answer?

Comment: I would to share the custom projection that I have made, but unfortunately the text is too long because I use the WKT projection.